# PostgreSQL: How can I check I am not using any key words?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How could I make sure I am not using any of [SQL and PostgreSQL's key words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-keywords-appendix.html), even the non-reserved ones, in my schema's identifiers (names for tables, columns...)?

Is there a way to do that with an SQL query?

Answer (score 2):

Check whether columnnames need to be quoted, by quoting them and comparing the result to the original.

```
SELECT * from pg_attribute
WHERE attname <> quote_ident(attname)
        ;

CREATE TABLE bad ("integer" integer not null primary key
        , "where" TEXT NOT NULL
        , "table" TEXT NOT NULL
        , "as" TEXT NOT NULL
        , "is" TEXT NOT NULL
        , "primary" TEXT NOT NULL
        , "references" TEXT NOT NULL
        );

SELECT * from pg_attribute
WHERE attname <> quote_ident(attname)

DROP TABLE bad cascade;
```

the above  will also catch MixedCaseIdentifiers. To suppress these, use:

```
CREATE TABLE mixed ("Mixed" integer not null primary key );

SELECT * from pg_attribute
WHERE lower(attname) <> quote_ident(lower(attname))
        ;

DROP TABLE mixed cascade;
```

But this will also catch identifiers with embedded spaces. To catch these, remove them before comparing:

```
CREATE TABLE spaced ("spa ced" integer not null primary key );

SELECT * from pg_attribute
WHERE lower(replace(attname, ' ' ,'') )
   <> quote_ident(lower(replace(attname, ' ' ,'')))
    ;
```

---

The same trick, wrapped into an SQL-function:

```
CREATE function check_needsquoting( str text ) returns Boolean AS
$func$
select lower(replace(str, ' ' ,'') )
   <> quote_ident(lower(replace(str, ' ' ,'')))
   ;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;

SELECT check_needsquoting ( 'FooBar' );
SELECT check_needsquoting ( 'where' );
SELECT check_needsquoting ( 'create' );

DROP function check_needsquoting( str text );
```

Result:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
 check_needsquoting 
--------------------
 f
(1 row)

 check_needsquoting 
--------------------
 t
(1 row)

 check_needsquoting 
--------------------
 t
(1 row)

DROP FUNCTION
```

---

Combining this function with the results from the `pg_get_keywords();` function mentioned by @vyegorov) yields:

```
SELECT
        kw.word, kw.catcode
        , check_needsquoting(kw.word) AS needsquote
from pg_get_keywords() kw
ORDER BY kw.word
        ;
```

Leading to the conclusion that only `catcode IN ( 'C', 'R' )` need to be quoted.
Note: `pg_get_keywords()` seems to be available since Postgresql-8.4. (and `quote_ident()` from *at least* Postgresql-7.2)

---

UPDATE: it appears **all** the words used in the syntax need to be detected, not only the reserved ones:

```
CREATE function check_ifsyntaxword( str text ) returns Boolean AS
$func$
select EXISTS(
        select 1
        from pg_get_keywords() kw
        WHERE lower(kw.word) = lower( str )
        )
   ;
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Comment: Thing is — identifiers are not only about attributes, but all other types of objects.

Comment: Yes, that is true, it was only a first effort. IIRC, there is a list of reserved words (keywords?) maintained in the postgres source, I don't know if it is also published as a (pseudo)table. Would be neat. Note: the above fragment catches "integer"; I expect it to catch "where", "as", "is", etc as well. UPDATE: I just checked: it does catch them.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * from pg_get_keywords();
```

This function is described in [the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE), but I found in [this e-mail thread](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/8440.1312467353@sss.pgh.pa.us).